# Vanity/Fancy/Rewrite URL implementation that does not suck

Tags: java, architecture, content-management-system

I have got a website, with really badly implemented Vanity URL module and really high loads at certain periods of time. Due to some bugs in the url module, the system needs to be restarted every so often. So, I want to rewrite a bloody module to make it nice and less buggy...

Is there are a good pattern to implementing Vanity URL system ?

What is the best approach when dealing with Vanity URL's for high performance ?

What is the best library to look at the sources ?

Cheers.
Ako

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: OSGi compatible, home brewed framework

Comment: You mean bare servlets?

Comment: Well for certain parts Sling is used, somewhere else Spring MVC is added, but main part is bare servlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the specific implementation details of your application, but as a general sketch I would write a `Filter` mapped to the space of URL of interest (perhaps `/*`).

Such `Filter` would *check if the URL is a fancy one*, and in that case would *`forward` the request to the appropiate resource* (either a URL dispatcher or a named one). You will need to save the `filterConfig.getServletContext()` passed in `init(FilterConfig)` in order to create the request dispatchers. If the URL is not fancy, the filter would invoke `chain.doFilter(req, resp)`, then serving a non-mapped resource.

```
public class ExceptionFilter implements Filter {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void destroy() {}
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, 
                         ServletResponse resp, 
                         FilterChain chain) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {        
        String mapping = getMappingFor((HttpServletRequest)req);
        if(mapping!=null) servletContext.getRequestDispatcher(mapping).forward(req,resp);
        else chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
       this.servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
    }

    private String getMappingFor(HttpServletRequest req) {...}
```

How `getMappingFor` is implemented, depends on the application, but it would probably open a connection to a database and ask whether URL /foo/bar is mapped, returning the mapped URL or `null`if there is no mapping. If the mappings are known not to change, you may cache those mappings already retrieved.

You may go with more detailed implementations, such as setting some request attributes depending on the given URL or information from the database, and then forwarding the request to some servlet that knows what to do.